# Multi select in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have a relationship beetwen tables members and companies in my app (HABTM), a member can have many companies, and a company can have many members, but a member can have no company, and a company must have at least one member.

so, when i create a company, it shows field for members (a multi select field), i want to automatically selects only the member who is creating the company as mandatory, and not permit the user to chosose.

Using bake, cake generated this code for the multiple select:

```
echo $this->Form->input('members._ids', ['options' => $members]);
```

and shows all members, i tried the following:

```
$id = $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User')['id'];
```

to catch the user who is creating the company, and then:

```
echo $this->Form->input('members._ids', ['options' => $members, 'default' => $id, 'type' => 'hidden']);
```

But is creating the company but not associating with the user, how can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it in the form, you can try setting the $id as *value* instead of *default* but that is not a recommended way here because form value, even if it is hidden, can be changed by the user/member. As you want to set the logged in member only, you can do it in your [*controller*](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations) before saving the company.

Recommended way of doing it :

```
// $companiesTable is your table model for the company and $company is the entity you would be creating and patching with the request data from the form
$memberEntity = $companiesTable->Members->get($id);
$company->members = [$memberEntity];
$companiesTable->save($company);
```

Comment: i apllied the recommended way, in my controller, its working like as expected, thanks.